# How do I add custom method to my linq entities without loosing changes when updating DB?

Tags: c#, linq

I am fairly new to C# and LINQ, but I have a small DB that I linked with my C# project using a `.dbml` file.

This works well, but I needed to add some stuff to the generated `.cs` file so I created custom methods and modified some properties of the entities, was okay, but as soon as I updated my `.dbml` file because I did a little fix in my DB, I lost all my changes.

Is it possible to update the `.cs` file after a DB change without losing all my "custom" stuff? If not, where should I put my custom stuffs to avoid losing it each time I update my DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code in a separate file with partial class. This way you will not change anything to the `*.dbml.cs` file.

Another option would be to use Entity framework Code first approach and define your own classes. It is much easier to change.

See: [Entity framework Code First with Existing Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)

Comment: Partial class looks like a good solution for me except for properties... Is there a way to handle annotation (such as `IsDbGenerated`, etc.) in a partial class? Because VS did not generated these annotations for my fields.